# Why is $| √2 - 1| = √2-1$ and $|3-π| = π - 3$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The absolute value of a number is the distance that number is from $0$ on the real number line. Distances are always positive or $0$.

$|\sqrt 2 - 1| =  \sqrt 2-1$. Why? This is an expression. Should I be setting it to $0$? However, $|3-π| = π - 3$. Why?

(I have asked my calculus teacher to explain and he has done a terrible job at doing so.)

Comment: Then improve the other question to narrow down what it is you don't understand or offer a bounty to increase its visibility. Do not add a duplicate question.